# The type or namespace 'system' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

I am compiling my first "Hello World" program of C# in mono compiler persist error

> The type or namespace 'system' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I googled it and it says I need to add reference and it isn't available for mono compiler. I don't know where and what to add. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Try it capitalized: `using System;`

Comment: Otherwise you add reference like this `mcs example.cs -r System.Web.dll` or install MonoDevelop to do that for you

Comment: @FilipBulovic -- good point (I don't use Mono) I think the `dll` for the OP would be `System.dll` so the comand might be: `mcs example.cs -r System.dll`

Comment: @DavidTanasey System.dll comes in by default, like on Microsofts implementation, no need to reference it. For Hello World  `mcs hello.cs` is sufficient, to execute `mono hello.exe` from terminal, if he is on Linux.

Comment: @FilipBulovic -- awesome information.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

The error message you've posted indicates that you are attempting to reference something in a namespace called `system` (note: lowercase).

C# namespaces are case-sensitive.  The namespace `System` needs to be capitalized when you reference it, either in a `using` statement as in:

```
using System;
```

or in a fully-qualified reference like this:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```